# How to create in one line a null vector of size 10 but the fifth value being 1 using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am able to do it in two lines for the numpy module:

```
x=np.zeros(10)
x[4]=1
```

However, I was wondering if its possible to combine the two together

Comment: Why do you want to do this in one line? It's almost certainly going to be less readable and slower…

Comment: @abarnert no reason, just want to learn by doing

Comment: You could do this: `x = np.zeros(10); x[4] = 1`, this is cheating, of  course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. For example, `np.arange(10) == 4` gives you an array of all `False` values except for one `True` at position 4.

Under the covers, NumPy's `bool` values are just `0` and `1` as `uint8` (just like Python's `bool` values are `0` and `1`, although of a unique integral type), so you can just use it as-is in any expression:

```
>>> np.arange(10) == 4
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> np.arange(10) * 1
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> np.arange(10) + 23
array([23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23])
```

… or `view` it as `uint8` instead of `bool`:

```
>>> (np.arange(10) == 4).view(np.uint8)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

… or, if you want normal `int` values, you can convert it:

```
>>> (np.arange(10) == 4).astype(int)
```

array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

And so on.

However, this seems a lot less readable, and it's also about 20% slower in a quick test, so unless you're doing this for code-golfing reasons, why?

Comment: Its less readable, but its good to learn the different sentence structures in python. Thanks!

Comment: `(np.arange(10) == 4).astype(int)` is faster.

Comment: And `(np.arange(10) == 4).view(np.uint8)` probably even faster.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: I get 5.44us vs. 5.49us, so… not so much, at least for this tiny case. It's certainly _more readable_, however, so +1, and edited into my answer.

Comment: @Jaime: Of course (4.28us vs. 5.48us), but then those aren't `int` values, they're just values that can be used together with `int` values, which `bool` already is. Still, certainly handy for, say, printing out to a human, so again, +1 and edited in.

Answer (score 4):

```
x = numpy.array([0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0])
```

:P

Comment: thats cheating, you can't type everything out

Answer (score 2):

Use this
`np.where(np.arange(10)==4,1,0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
b=np.array([int(x==4) for x in range(10)])
print(b)


[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a null vector of size 10 but the fifth value which is 1.

```
import numpy
x = np.zeros(10, dtype=int)
if x[5] == 0:
   x[5] = 1  
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't that it is possible to combine:

```
x=np.zeros(10) #1 create an array of values 
x[4]=1         #2 assign at least one value of an array a different value
```

in one line.

Naive:

```
x = np.zeros(10)[4] = 1 # Fails
```

fails as value of `x` is `1` due how python handles chained assignment. Both `x` and `element 4` in array of zeros are assigned value `1`.

Therefore, we need to first create an array of zeros, and then assign element assign `element 4` a value of `1`, and these two cannot be done in one line.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this to multiple elements:

```
my_vect = np.zeros(42)
# set index 1 and 3 to value 1
my_vect[np.array([1,3])] = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
array = numpy.eye( array_size )[ element_in_array_which_should_be_1 - 1 ]
```

So to create a null vector of size 10 but the fifth value being 1 in one line is

```
array = numpy.eye( 10 ) [ 5 - 1 ]
```

===> array([0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])

:)